# Upload files through Python Wrapper around Mega api

Tags: python-2.7, api

I'm using python 2.7 Wrapper of Mega Api on Ubuntu. With the following code I could upload a set of files to my Mega Account, however I'd like to know how I can upload files to a specific folder on my account.

```
from mega import Mega
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mega = Mega()
mega._login_user('email','password')

def absoluteFilePaths(directory):
   for dirpath,_,filenames in os.walk(directory):
       for f in filenames:
           yield os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))

directory = '/home/caioignm/test_folder'
file_path_generator = absoluteFilePaths(directory)

for file_path in file_path_generator:
    mega.upload(file_path)
```

On my Mega Account, I have one folder, 'Personal', with other folder inside, 'Vacations', where all my files are stored. When I upload without refering a destination path, the files are stored in root directory.

I tried to follow help instructions of mega package, but I didn't find out how to set destination folder of my files.

```
Help on method upload in module mega.mega:

upload(self, filename, dest=None, dest_filename=None) method of mega.mega.Mega instance
    ##########################################################################
    # UPLOAD
```

Doing `mega.upload('filename', 'Personal/Vacations')` I haven't received any error message, but my files were not uploaded too

Comment: Try `mega.uploadfile('filename', 'Personal/Vacations')`

Comment: Does not work. Doing so, the files are not uploaded

Comment: Which Python Wrapper of Mega api are you using? There many different python wrappers of MEGA API. As I know, this is one: https://github.com/richardARPANET/mega.py/blob/master/src/mega/mega.py, and this is another one: https://github.com/meganz/sdk/tree/develop/bindings/python, and also some other versions, I don't list them.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/richardARPANET/mega.py/blob/master/src/mega/mega.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was so easy, like this:

```
Folder = mega.find('my_mega_folder')
mega.upload('yourfile.txt', Folder[0])
```

I have added it to your code:

```
from mega import Mega
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mega = Mega()
mega._login_user('email','password')

def absoluteFilePaths(directory):
     for dirpath,_,filenames in os.walk(directory):
       for f in filenames:
           yield os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f))

directory = '/home/caioignm/test_folder'
file_path_generator = absoluteFilePaths(directory)

Folder = mega.find('your_folder') #change it with the folder in your mega
for file_path in file_path_generator:
    mega.upload(file_path, Folder[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

> Upload a file to a destination folder:
>
> ```
> folder = m.find('my_mega_folder')
> m.upload('myfile.doc', folder[0])
> ```

Source : https://pypi.org/project/mega.py/